# How can I wait for a file to be finished being written to in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script called `parent.sh` which does some stuff, then goes off and calls another shell script `child.sh` which does some processing and writes some output to a file `output.txt`.

I would like the `parent.sh` script to only continue processing *after* that `output.txt` file has been written to. How can I know that the file has finished being written to?

Edit: Adding answers to questions:
*Does child.sh finish writing to the file before it exits?* Yes

*Does parent.sh run child.sh in the foreground or the background?*  I'm not sure - it's being called from withing `parent.sh` like this: `./child.sh "$param1" "$param2"`

Comment: Does `child.sh` finish writing to the file before it exits? Does `parent.sh` run `child.sh` in the foreground or the background?

Comment: To follow up on @EtanReisner 's questions, let me try the prior question: what makes you think that the parent script is continuing *before* output.txt has been fully written out?

Comment: I guess I have assumed that the execution of the child script will be forked in another process, and that the parent script will therefore continue executing in the first process. Please correct me if this assumption is wrong!

Comment: you have to use the 'run-in-the-background-character', i.e. `&` at the end of the command line for the child process. You're 2nd edit example should work as you want, without changes. The parent process will not continue from child unless the child is 'run-in-the-background'. Good luck.

Comment: As you said, your `child.sh` runs at foreground (since it has no `&` after that line), and thus your `parent.sh` will just continue the next line after `child.sh` line, when the `child.sh` ends. Nothing special to fix.  YET, if your `child.sh` generates background processes, that's another story.

Answer (score 4):

You need the `wait` command.  `wait` will wait until all sub-processes have finished before continuing.

parent.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm output.txt

./child.sh &

# Wait for the child script to finish
#
wait

echo "output.txt:"
cat output.txt
```

child.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
for x in $(seq 10); do
    echo $x >&2
    echo $x
    sleep 1
done > output.txt
```

Here is the output from `./parent.sh`:

```
[sri@localhost ~]$ ./parent.sh 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
output.txt:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```